# How do I combine static text and fields into a single field

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to do this for multiple fields and text

So in one field I would want it be TEXT FIELD TEXT FIELD TEXT FIELD

So it would be L 12 X W 12 X 12

The letters would be static text and the numbers would be an actual field

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a Formula Field to do this.  Within the Formula Field you can concatenate plain text with database fields.  Here is an example of a formula for a Formula Field.

```
"This is my custom string." & {table.column} & " more custom text.";
```

This formula will concatenate the first string contained within the double quotes, the value of {table.column}, and the second string contained within double quotes.  If we assume the value of {table.column} is "Delta365", then the output of the formula field would be the following:

`This is my custom text. Delta365 more custom text.`

EDIT: Response to follow-up question.

To remove the decimal from a numeric value while using a formula to concatenate the numeric value to a string of text you should use one of the overloaded `ToText()` function.  `ToText(x,y)` is the most commonly used versions of this function.  Here is a breakdown of the arguments for this function.

- x is a Number or Currency value to be converted into a text string.
- y is a Format String that determines how the value of x will be
  displayed.

There are two ways to use this function to remove the decimal point.  Here is an example of each method using the same example I used previously.

```
"This is my custom string." & ToText({table.column},0) & " more custom text.";
```

Or

```
"This is my custom string." & ToText({table.column},"#") & " more custom text.";
```

The difference between these two formulas is the value of the y argument.  When `y = 0`, the value of {table.column} will be rounded to the nearest whole number.  When `y = "#"`, the value of {table.column} is not rounded and instead will truncate and not show any digits beyond the decimal point.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was trying this earlier and it wasn't working but now I tried and it is. Weird. One more question if you dont mind. How do I format the numbers within the string to not show two decimal places. So I want it to say L 48 W 48 H 48 rather then L 48.00 W 48.00 H 48.00

Comment: @BillReilly The answer to your follow-up question has been added to my original answer above.  It was a bit more than I could easily fit within a comment, so editing the answer seemed to be the best option to help you.